Invitation to signup with firebase
I'm building an invitation signup in next js with firebase. Here is the flow I want to achieve:

admin enters email id to be invited and clicks enter. Then a invitation link should be sent to that email with firebase.
when user clicks on that it should be redirected to a page where user can set his password and submits. Then his credentials should be saved in db.

Note: this link should be expired like in a day. And once that invitation link is used to signup it should be expired.
try using sendEmailverificaction()
Tech : next js/node and firebase
I used sendEmailverificaction() but when I used it I couldn't get the user email from the oobcode of that firebase link. So that I can use that email and password that user enters to create new user in firebase.

Admin Sends Invitation Email
Create an API route in Next.js to handle the sending of the invitation email.
// pages/api/sendInvitation.js
import { getAuth } from 'firebase-admin/auth';
import { initializeApp, applicationDefault, cert } from 'firebase-admin/app';

const serviceAccount = require('../../path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');

initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount)
});

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  
  if (!email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email is required' });
  }

  try {
    const link = await getAuth().generateSignInWithEmailLink(email, {
      url: 'http://yourdomain.com/completeSignup', // URL to redirect to after email verification
      handleCodeInApp: true
    });

    // Send email logic here (using nodemailer, SendGrid, etc.)

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Invitation sent' });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};

User Sets Password and Submits
Create a page in Next.js for the user to set their password after clicking the invitation link.
// pages/completeSignup.js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { getAuth, confirmSignInWithEmailLink, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  // your firebase config
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export default function CompleteSignup() {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const email = window.localStorage.getItem('emailForSignIn');
      if (!email) {
        throw new Error('Email not found');
      }

      if (confirmSignInWithEmailLink(auth, email, window.location.href)) {
        await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        setMessage('User created successfully');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Complete Signup</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Set Password"
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <p>{message}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

Handle Link Expiration and Usage
To ensure the link expires after a day and is invalid after use, you can leverage Firebase Authentication's built-in features. The generateSignInWithEmailLink method already handles expiration and one-time usage. The only additional step is to ensure the email is stored temporarily when the link is generated and cleared after the user completes the signup.
Integrate Email Sending Logic
Integrate your preferred email sending service (like nodemailer, SendGrid, etc.) in the sendInvitation API route to send the generated link.
Full Example of Sending Email with Nodemailer
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

// Assuming you have the email link generation code here

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'your-email@gmail.com',
    pass: 'your-email-password'
  }
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: 'your-email@gmail.com',
  to: email,
  subject: 'Complete your signup',
  html: `<p>Click <a href="${link}">here</a> to complete your signup.</p>`
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  }
  console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
});

Clear Local Storage After Signup
Make sure to clear the local storage after the user completes the signup:
if (confirmSignInWithEmailLink(auth, email, window.location.href)) {
  await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  window.localStorage.removeItem('emailForSignIn'); // Clear email from local storage
  setMessage('User created successfully');
}


I don't want to use any 3rd party to send mail. I want to use the firbase itself. and also there is no confirmSignInWithEmailLink in firebase auth. Is there a way to get the email from oobcode or link generated using sendEmailVerification() or can we do this using sendEmailVerification() ?
